# Solr: Use a count or weighting number in source documents to weight search results

Tags: solr, lucene, solr6

I have a Solr Index that is largely composed of repeated terms. I'm trying to return results scores weighted by the number of occurrences of each term. The problem with this is that the index is enormous, as a result. I'd like a way to shrink this down. Something like Solr understanding "myterm:500" means that there are 500 instances of myterm for this record. I've also run into an upper limit for multivariate text_general fields by simply repeating terms.

Is there a way to do this? Can I shrink my indexes by several orders of magnitude?

Comment: have you checked payloads and index time term boosts? http://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/06/13/end-to-end-payload-example-in-solr/